# Disabling the taxonomy field - drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have added a taxonomy field to my entity via the module install file and I need to disable this field i.e. I need it to look the same as a normal field in the form that has the `'disabled' => TRUE,` settings.

What do I have to type in the instance creation code: `field_create_instance($instance);` to make this work? and where should I type it? i.e. inside the widget code? or just as a normal parameter of the instance array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using `field_create_instance` as that function/system has no concept of a `disabled` attribute on the input element.

You'll need to use a `hook_form_alter` to add a `disabled` attribute to the elements you require.

Comment: I am a little confused about where to add this code and what I have to type into it.  If I create that function and place it in the install file, do I then have to call this function (with the paramaters typed in it) in the hook_install?